# Efficient de-deduplication (memoization) of objects in Java, shortcomings of HashSet

Tags: java, c++

So I am working on some data-structure, whose operations tend to generate lots of different instances of a certain type. The datasets can be large enough to potentially yield millions of such objects. It is crucial that I "memoize" them, since there are recurring patterns in these calculations.

Typically the way memoization is done is that you simply have a set (say, a HashMap with its keys as its values) of all instances ever created. Any time an operation would return a result, instead the set is searched for an existing, identical object. If the object is found, it is returned instead, and the result we looked up with instantly becomes garbage.

Now, this is straight-forward enough. However, HashMap is not a perfect fit for this use case. There are two points I will address here:

1. Lack of support for custom equality and hashing function
2. Lack of support for "equivalent key" lookup.

The first has already been discussed (question 5453226), though not sufficiently for my purposes; solutions in the form of "just wrap your key types with another object" are a non-starter. If the key is a relatively small object (e.g. an array or a string of small size) the overhead cost of these wrappers can be nearly 2X.

To illustrate the second point, let's say the data type I'd like to memoize is a (typically small) `int[]`. Suppose I have made an operation and it has yielded a result, but it is not exactly in an `int[]`, rather, it consists of a `int[] x` and separately a length `int length`. What I would like to do now is to look up the set for an array that equals (as a sequence of ints) to the data in `x[0..length-1]`. In principle, there should be no problem to accomplish this, provided that the user supplies equality and hashing predicates that match the ones used for the key type itself. In principle, the "compatible key" (`x` and `length` here) doesn't even have to be materialized as an object.

The lack of "compatible key" lookups may cause to program to create temporary key objects that are likely to be thrown away afterwards.

Problem 1 prevents me from using something like `int[]` as a key type in a Map, since it doesn't have the hashing and equality functions that I want. Further, I actually want to use shallow / reference-only comparisons and hashing on these objects once I'm past the memoization step, since then x is an identical object to y iff `x == y`. Here we have the same key type, but different desired equality/hashing behavior.

In C++, the functionality in (1) is offered out of the box by most hash-table based containers. (2) is given by some container types, for example the associative container templates in the Boost library.

A third function I'd be interested in (less important) is the `insert_check`/`insert_commit` idea, where we first check if a matching key exist, and we also get some implementation-defined marker back (e.g. bucket index). Then if we do create a new key and want to insert it, we give back the marker and it's inserted to the right place in the data structure. There is no reason why the hash of the same key should be computed twice.

If the compiler (or JIT) is clever enough to avoid double lookup in this scenario, that is a preferable solution - it's easier not to have to worry about it. I just never actually tested if it is.

Are there any libraries known to offer any of these capabilities in Java? Do I have to roll my own? Am I missing something?

Comment: "Lack of support for custom equality and hashing function" Except that you're free to implement the equals and hash code function for the things you store. Wrap your values in a different type, if that's what you need.

Comment: unless it's something like int[]. Unless I want one set to check equality and hash "deeply", in order to deduplicate, and all other maps can use reference equality and default hashcode because it's already been deduplicated...have you read the entire post?

Comment: I also mentioned there can be potentially millions of keys, I'd rather not pay the extra cost of several million wrapper objects on top of them unless there is absolutely no way to avoid it. That is essentially what I was asking - if it can be avoided at all